# Is it possible to concatenate the result of two of promql?

Tags: prometheus, promql

The result of two of promql below would have same label.
1.sum by(workload) (label_replace(kube_replicaset_status_replicas{},"workload","$1","replicaset","(.+)"))
2.sum by(workload) (label_replace(kube_statefulset_replicas{},"workload","$1","statefulset","(.+)"))

ex)

1. sum by(workload) (label_replace(kube_replicaset_status_replicas{},"workload","$1","replicaset","(.+)"))

```json
{
        "metric": {
          "workload": "zmx"
        },
        "value": [
          1669274927.023,
          "0"
        ]
  },{
        "metric": {
          "workload": "efg"
        },
        "value": [
          1669274927.023,
          "0"
        ]
  }
```

2. sum by(workload) (label_replace(kube_statefulset_replicas{},"workload","$1","statefulset","(.+)"))

```json
{
        "metric": {
          "workload": "abc"
        },
        "value": [
          1669274927.023,
          "0"
        ]
  },{
        "metric": {
          "workload": "efg"
        },
        "value": [
          1669274927.023,
          "0"
        ]
  }
```

The concatenation would look like below

```json
{
        "metric": {
          "workload": "abc"
        },
        "value": [
          1669274927.023,
          "0"
        ]
  },{
        "metric": {
          "workload": "efg"
        },
        "value": [
          1669274927.023,
          "0"
        ]
  },{
        "metric": {
          "workload": "zmx"
        },
        "value": [
          1669274927.023,
          "0"
        ]
  },{
        "metric": {
          "workload": "efg"
        },
        "value": [
          1669274927.023,
          "0"
        ]
  }
```

Can I get the result above directly from a single promql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the "or" operator:

```
sum by(workload) (label_replace(kube_replicaset_status_replicas{},"workload","$1","replicaset","(.+)")) or sum by(workload) (label_replace(kube_statefulset_replicas{},"workload","$1","statefulset","(.+)"))
```

Comment: It's my pleasure that it helps